# Conditional probability from decision tree based on biased sampling

Tags: bayesian, sampling, conditional-probability, cart, decision-theory

I have a very simple binary decision tree trained with a depth of 2 as shown below. There are two labels (e.g. **a**, **b**). For example, In the root node, there are Na samples labeled as **a**, and Nb samples labeled as **b**. The same naming convention goes with variables in the two children nodes.

[image]

My goal is to obtain a probability of a sample being of label **a** given that it meets the particular condition, C (i.e. f <= x, where f and x are a feature and a cutoff learned by the decision tree during training process).

I thought it would be just about simple bayesian statistics and calculated as

```
P(a|C) = P(a, C) / P(C)
```

where

```
P(a, C) = La / (Na + Nb)
```

and

```
P(C) = (La + Lb) / (Na + Nb)
```

so

```
P(a|C) = La / (La + Lb)
```

Nice and clean. I thought I could conclude that given a new sample and C is met, then the probability of it being of label **a** would be `La / (La + Lb)`

However, I realized that the sampling process is **biased** in the data collection process. In particular, samples of Label **a** is **over-sampled**, so I thought `P(a, C)` and `P(C)` as calculated above won't reflect the true distribution anymore. My question is that will my analysis above still be valid? If not, is there a way to correct the bias introduced during the sampling process?